# Can I convert a local user to a common user in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I have a local user in a pluggable database and it has data, objects etc. under its schema.

Can I easily convert this user to a common user without losing its objects etc.? (Oracle Database 19c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - No.

You can't convert between common and local user accounts.

Even if you *could*, where would the database store the account's "data and objects"?
You should not have any user/application data in the Container Database.